# How to hide collapse trigger Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

How can I hide the collapse trigger in Bootstrap when the collapsed text is being shown?

What I have right now is a table with a column for a description, but when the description is longer than 150 characters I truncate the string and add "..." to the end. I've been playing around with Bootstrap and I managed to make it as an `<a>` element which acts as a trigger for a collapsed `<div>`, which holds the rest of the description, so that when someone clicks it the rest is shown. What I would like to do is hide the dots once someone clicks them and add the rest of the description in their place, would this be possible?

This is the current snippet of Javascript that I'm using:

```
if (key == "Description") {
    values.textContent = Json.prods[i][key].substring(0,150);
    if (Json.prods[i][key].length > 150){
        values.innerHTML += "<a data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#descr'>...</a>";
        values.innerHTML += "<div id='descr' class='collapse'>"+Json.prods[i][key].substring(150,Json.prods[i][key].length)+"</div>";
    }
}
```

I want to specify that as of now what I see in the table when I click the dots is something like:

```
first_150_chars...
rest_of_description
```

While I would like to see:

```
first_150_chars_rest_of_description
```

Comment: The trigger has the class `collapsed` when the content is hidden, and that class gets removed when the content is shown … so simply write a CSS rule that hides it based on that.